# Paste event doesn't work on Firefox 53.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(".numericPaste").bind(
            "paste",
            function(e) {

                var clipboardData = e.clipboardData
                        || e.originalEvent.clipboardData
                        || window.clipboardData;

                var dataToBePasted = clipboardData.getData('text');
                console.log('Data to be Pasted: ' + dataToBePasted);

                return true;
            });
```

But the above code works fine on chrome, but doesn't work on Firefox 53.0.3

Comment: Does the event fire?  Do you see any errors in the logs?  You mention a specific Firefox version - have you tried other versions - did it work there?

Comment: works for me on 53.0.3 on osx Sierra. Try to restart FF in safe mode (without any plugins)

Comment: No. The event doesn't fires only when i try to paste using `ctrl + v`. But it works when i tried to paste using right-click of mouse.

Comment: Firefox - 53.0.3;
OS - Ubutnu 14.04